# Is it possible to blur the content under my navigation bar?

Tags: html, css

I need as clean code as I can get to get to an effect I have tried to achieve, to no avail:
http://logandark.net/images/blur.png
I am trying to ask the questions the best I can because I have been blocked from asking questions before, and I do not intend to be blocked again...
So please, try and find me something that will help...

I will explain this in the best I can:
1. There is a navigation bar at the top with position:fixed
2. The content that is under the navigation bar gets blurred (because the bar is partially transparent)
3. That content gets unblurred if it is not under the navigation bar

I don't care if this requires javascript that scrolls content positioned under the bar that scrolls when you scroll down or up, I don't care if it is fancy and complicated and tricky, I just need to find answers!
Everything I google talks about the -webkit-filter CSS property, and that's for an element's CHILD elements! It can't be controlled easily!

Please, correct me if I'm wrong, but this will not be very easy. Please respond, and if you do, try to explain it as much as possible.

Comment: Sorry but its not very clear what your asking. If your looking for a full solution then your best bet would be Stack Overflow due to heavy coding CSS/HTML. If its related to SEO or other things Webmaster then please edit your question and make it more clear what your asking... generally a good question is short after a brief introduction.

Comment: You cant do this with CSS3 blur because it will not affect the div scrolling below.  The only possible way right now is with Javascript + Canvas, where you take canvas snapshots on scroll, and then blur them using either canvas or CSS3.   I have seen this done a few times and each time it is a total memory hog.  Your best bet is just to use transparent glass color and forget about the blur.  Apple does this on their new homepage and it looks very nice.   The only time I would recommend using the canvas technique is if the image is generated only once, scrolling would create tons of images.